# How can I fix the 'remote authorization server is currently unavailable or returned an invalid configuration' error in OpenIdDict version 4.4.0?

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, swagger-ui, openiddict

I have two applications - authorization server and resource server. For testing I use swagger. Resource server swagger authorizes and obtains access token successfully. But when I'm trying to GET authorized resource with token - I've got exception `www-authenticate: Bearer error="server_error",error_description="The remote authorization server is currently unavailable or returned an invalid configuration.",error_uri="https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2170"`

OpenIdDict version is 4.4.0.

Resource Server configuration

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:7200/");
        options.AddAudiences("resource_server_1");

        options.AddEncryptionKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Convert.FromBase64String("DRjd/GnduI3Efzen9V9BvbNUfc/VKgXltV7Kbk9sMkY=")));

        options.UseSystemNetHttp();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:7200/connect/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:7200/connect/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "api1", "resource server scope" }
                }
            },
        }
    });

    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }
            },
            Array.Empty<string>()
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.OAuthClientId("web-client");
    c.OAuthClientSecret("901564A5-E7FE-42CB-B10D-61EF6A8F3654");
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Authorization Server Configuration

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using OidcAuthorizationServer;
using static OpenIddict.Abstractions.OpenIddictConstants;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    options.UseOpenIddict<Guid>();
});

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options
            .UseEntityFrameworkCore()
            .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .ReplaceDefaultEntities<Guid>();
    })
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("connect/authorize")
                .SetLogoutEndpointUris("connect/logout")
                .SetTokenEndpointUris("connect/token");

        options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email, Scopes.Profile, Scopes.Roles);

        options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();

        options.AddEncryptionKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Convert.FromBase64String("DRjd/GnduI3Efzen9V9BvbNUfc/VKgXltV7Kbk9sMkY=")));

        options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

        options.UseAspNetCore()
                .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();
    });

builder.Services.AddTransient<AuthorizationService>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

// FIXME спецификация определяет способ аутентификации владельца ресурсов, поэтому использование COOKIE не обязательно
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(c =>
    {
        c.LoginPath = "/Authenticate";
    });

builder.Services.AddTransient<ClientsSeeder>();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7201")
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var seeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ClientsSeeder>();
    
    seeder.AddClients().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    seeder.AddScopes().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

When I try to downgrade OpenIdDict version to 4.0.0 - resource server show error `Error description: An error occurred while communicating with the remote HTTP server. Error URI: https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2136` at the start. But swagger still opens and token getting works.

[image]

Comment: Can it actually reach the discovery document and the document returned is a JSON document? see my blog post here https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/